# How to measure sit bone distance if I am very fat?

Tags: mountain-bike, saddle, riding-position, gel-saddle

I saw many people over the Internet suggesting I sit on a cardboard with my feet a little lifted, mimicking my riding position, and then marking the place with chalk to reveal ny sit bones footprints. However, as a ~140kg man, this does not seem to work (no traces left in the cardboard), but I am unsure I did it right.

Could you kindly suggest other methods / how I could make this work? I want this in order to grab a saddle.

Comment: Some of the methods in answers to the following question may help you:
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/9815/30402

Comment: In my mind, the gold standard would be x-ray measurement.  I don't know how readily available that is, though, so this may be sufficiently difficult as to be a non-starter.

Answer (score 2):

Many bike stores have a foam cube that you sit on for a few minutes. When you get up, the impression of your sit bones is etched in the foam and can be measured. The good bike stores will walk you through that before selling you a new saddle.

Comment: "memory foam" will do this nicely - some modern mattresses and pillows have this foam

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I measured my sit bone distance.

I bought a cheap "Gel" saddle from a department store. I rode it for a while. The cheap "Gel" padding in the department store bought saddle compressed permanently, leaving marks at where my sit bones touch the saddle.

The cheap "Gel" saddle thus confirmed that the most common saddle width, ~14 cm, is ideal for me. Then I bought a good quality saddle from a bicycle parts store in the same width.

Now, this may not be a practical way but it's interesting that such poor saddles that deform permanently are sold. The main problem in the practicality of this method is that no saddle is advertised by the padding permanently deforming.